# Which is correct, "counselor/advocates" or "counselors/advocates"?

Tags: grammatical-number, slash

I am editing a manual and I came across the phrase "counselor/advocates" quite a bit. I always believed that if you were discussing two similar things that were plural and used a backslash to separate them, you were supposed to write them both in the plural form, as in "counselors/advocates", instead of just writing the second word in plural form, as in "counselor/advocates", but I am not sure. Can anyone provide any clarity on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anecdotally (therefore a comment, not an answer), I see "counselors/advocates" when one could be referring to multiple people, any of whom might be a counselor or an advocate. If the reference is to multiple people, each of whom fills both roles (i.e., is a 'counselor/advocate'), I see it as "counselor/advocates".

Comment: Two wholly different things, T.Turner.

Of course, similar plural things using a backslash to separate them are supposed both to be written in plural form…

If you want help here why have you not explained your research, at least, and preferably outlined your conclusion for analysis?

Answer (score -1):

By the way, am I the only one who finds it rather scary that you're 'editing a manual and I came across the phrase "counselor/advocates" quite a bit,' please?

D'you not think that should be 'I come across…'or "I have come across…" or at best, "while editing a manual, I came accross" but never what you suggested?

Comment: Please, People; don't play games and do stick to the meaning of both Question and Answer…